Not able to write a specific package name for android app in flutter
I'm trying to build a app named chatapp and while creating it package name should be mentioned. I tried to write the package name as com.example.chatapp but it only wrote com only three letters can be written in the package name and later on it shows that com is not a valid package name, it should be something like "com.example.chatapp".


In a confirmation phase of your package name you have to write it completely , here you just typed com instead of com.example.chatapp . If you can't type it completely , open it in android studio and try with terminal of android studio. I already faces with this issue and fixed it like this solution.
